# Angular UI-Router pass resolve to child onEnter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to pass a previously-resolved result from a parent to a modal instance that is instantiated `onEnter`, however the controller reports that it's an unknown provider:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: resolvedRouteProvider <- resolvedRoute
```

Is there another way to inject this value, or am I restricted to only calling services from `onEnter` functions?

For reference, the error occurs when navigating to a state like the child below:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('parent',
    resolve:
      resolvedRoute: (Restangular) -> Restangular.all('route')
  )
  .state('child',
    parent: 'parent',
    onEnter: ($modal) ->
      $modal.open(
        templateUrl: 'templates/modal.html',
        controller: 'ModalCtrl'
      )
  )
```

The controller is super-simple at this point:

```
.controller('ModalCtrl', ($scope, $modalInstance, resolvedRoute) ->
  $scope.object = {}
  $scope.createObject = ->
    resolvedRoute.all('objects').post({object: $scope.object})
)
```

---

### [Plunker with failing resolve](http://plnkr.co/edit/tPQmiE9B1tsixMikKdRU)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that you just need to pass another resolve through to the modal as well, e.g.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('parent',
    resolve:
      parentResolve: (Restangular) -> Restangular.all('route')
  )
  .state('child',
    parent: 'parent'
    url: '/child'
    resolve:
      childResolve: (Restangular) -> Restangular.one('bar')
    onEnter: ($modal) ->
      $modal.open(
        templateUrl: 'templates/modal.html',
        controller: 'ModalCtrl'
        resolve:
          parentResolve: -> parentResolve
          childResolve: -> childResolve
      )
  )
```

The `ModalCtrl` will now have access to the `parentResolve` and the `childResolve`.

**Please note:** the resolves have to be returned from functions, so simply resolving the same object **will not work**.

```
resolve:
  parentResolve: parentResolve
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example which it shows how you can inject data that is resolved to the onEnter function
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

like so:

```js
$stateProvider.state("contacts", {
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  resolve: { title: 'My Contacts' },
  controller: function($scope, title){
    $scope.title = 'My Contacts';
  },
  onEnter: function(title){
    if(title){ ... do something ... }
  },
  onExit: function(title){
    if(title){ ... do something ... }
  }
})
```